# How to make powercmd to load a custom PowerCmd.ini?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have multiple projects and each of them needs different commands. I save them in the Quick Launch panel.

So for project A I have 10 commands and for project B also have 10, but are different.

I would like to have powercmd with only the commands of project A or B depending on which I'm working. Is there any way?

I don't matter if there is any alternative to powercmd that can hold 4 opened cmd windows in grid and do the above.

(For windows 8 and xp, if possible)

Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to copy PowerCmd to 2 folders, and launch different powercmd for different projects. PowerCmd saves the quick launch config in the application folder.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm currently doing... But I would like to have just one powercmd and multiple config files.